# ASP.NET MVC Use validation on class property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have a simple model in my ASP.NET MVC app that I wish to put validation on a property which is a class.  I've looked at ScottGu's blog [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/class-level-model-validation-with-ef-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-3) on class-level validation but the validation occurs when `SaveChanges()` is called on the context, which I don't want.  I'd like it to react like the validation you get with `DataAnnotations` where it happens upon form submission.

Here's my model:

```
public class SignupModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company Name Required")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company Type")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company Type Required")]
    public int SelectedCompanyTypeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Requested Services")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "At least 1 service is required")]
    public PostedServicesOffered PostedServices { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ServicesOffered> ServicesOffered { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ServicesOffered> SelectedServicesOffered { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CompanyTypes { get; set; }
}
```

The `PostedServicesOffered` object is a simple class that has one property:

```
public class PostedServicesOffered
{
    public string[] ServiceOfferedIds { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        SignupModel model = new SignupModel()
        {
            CompanyTypes = SelectCompanyType(),
            ServicesOffered = GetServicesOffered(),
            SelectedServicesOffered = new List<ServicesOffered>(),
            PostedServices = new PostedServicesOffered()
        };

        ViewBag.BannerText = "Sign Up Form";

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SignupModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }

        return View(GetSignupModel(model));
    }

    private SignupModel GetSignupModel(SignupModel model)
    {
        SignupModel signupModel = new SignupModel();
        var selectedServices = new List<ServicesOffered>();
        var postedServicesOfferedIds = new string[0];

        if (model.PostedServices == null)
            model.PostedServices = new PostedServicesOffered();

        // if a view model array of posted services ids exists
        // and is not empty,save selected ids
        if (model.PostedServices.ServiceOfferedIds != null && model.PostedServices.ServiceOfferedIds.Any())
            postedServicesOfferedIds = model.PostedServices.ServiceOfferedIds;

        //If there are any selected ids saved, create a list of ServicesOffered.
        if (postedServicesOfferedIds.Any())
            selectedServices = GetServicesOffered()
                                .Where(x => postedServicesOfferedIds.Any(s => x.ServicesOfferedId.ToString().Equals(s)))
                                .OrderBy(x => x.ServiceName)
                                .ToList();

        signupModel.CompanyTypes = SelectCompanyType();
        signupModel.ServicesOffered = GetServicesOffered();
        signupModel.SelectedServicesOffered = selectedServices;
        signupModel.PostedServices = model.PostedServices;
        signupModel.SelectedCompanyTypeId = model.SelectedCompanyTypeId;

        return signupModel;
    }

    private IEnumerable<ServicesOffered> GetServicesOffered()
    {
        return Repository.GetServicesOffered(new UnitOfWork()).OrderBy(so => so.ServiceName);
    }

    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectCompanyType()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var companyTypes = Repository.GetCompanyTypes(new UnitOfWork()).OrderBy(ct => ct.CompanyType1);

        foreach (CompanyType companyType in companyTypes)
            items.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = companyType.CompanyType1,
                Value = companyType.CompanyTypeId.ToString()
            });

        return items;
    }
```

and the View:

```
<div id="contact-form" class="contatct-form">
    <h4 class="classic-title"><span>Registration</span></h4>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="validation-text">
            <h5>@Html.ValidationSummary()</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="row padBtm-20">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.CompanyName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CompanyName, new { placeholder = "Company Name..." })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SelectedCompanyTypeId)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCompanyTypeId, Model.CompanyTypes)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SelectedCompanyTypeId, new { value = Model.SelectedCompanyTypeId })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostedServices)<br />
                @*@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.PostedServices.ServiceOfferedIds,
                                        model => model.ServicesOffered,
                                        service => service.ServicesOfferedId,
                                        service => service.ServiceName,
                                        model => model.SelectedServicesOffered,
                                        Position.Vertical)*@
                @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.PostedServices,
                                        model => model.ServicesOffered,
                                        service => service.ServicesOfferedId,
                                        service => service.ServiceName,
                                        model => model.SelectedServicesOffered,
                                        Position.Vertical)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row padBtm-20"></div>                        
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send Message" />
    }

</div>
```

In short, the `ServicesOffered` property is a list of services that are displayed as CheckBoxes.  I am using a NeGut package called `MvcCheckBoxList` (found [here)](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/613785/How-to-Use-CheckBoxListFor-With-ASP-NET-MVC) which creates a set of checkboxes based on a list.

What's happening is when I click `Submit` with **no** checkboxes checked, the form validates the other properties first ans displays those error messages **first**.  It's only **after** those fields pass validation and the form is posted, that the `PostedServices` field fails validation and shows the error.  How can I get it to validate without posting like all the other properties?

Comment: what type of Validation do you want to perform on the checkboxes? You should be able to add data annotations to the list as well. If your validation is more complex then you can always have the model implement `IValidatableObject`

Comment: Of all the checkboxes that are generated, at least 1 needs to be selected.  I tried to have the model inherit from `IValidatableObject` but the `Validate` event never fires when the submit button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are encapsulating your string array inside of another class. Let me break down what's happening at validation, so you can understand why this isn't working.

First, validation happens both client-side and server-side. The problem you seem to have is that everything else but this property is validated client-side. Then, once the form actually posts, this particular property fails server-side and causes the form to redisplay at that point. The client-side validation happens by adding `data-*` attributes to the form fields. These attributes in turn inform the client-side validation code what type of validation to run. The `Required` attribute obviously makes the client-side code force a value to be entered, but the problem is that your `PostedServices` property is not represented on your form anywhere. Instead, you have a field for `PostedServices.ServiceOfferedIds` which notably is *not* required.

Once the form is posted, the modelbinder news up an instance of `SignupModel`, mapping over the posted data. However, since nothing is being posted for `ServiceOfferedIds`, it has nothing with which to create an instance of `PostedServicesOffered` and therefore sets the `PostedServices` property to `null`. Then, the `Required` validation catches server-side.

I'm not sure why you chose to encapsulate this one property in another class, but if you change your `PostedServices` to:

```
[Display(Name = "Requested Services")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "At least 1 service is required")]
public string[] PostedServices { get; set; }
```

So that you're interacting with the string array directly, everything should work fine.

Comment: thanks for the in-depth explanation, I now understand why it's happening that way.  I was following the example that the site used for that NuGet package (I added it to my question), which is why it is setup the way it is.  I tried your suggestion but I still can't get it to validate (I had to comment out the `GetSignupModel` function because it was looking for `.ServiceOfferedIds` property off of `PostedServices`.

Comment: Does the `MvcCheckBoxList` come with any JavaScript? The validation for a list of checkboxes is going to be custom because you have to look at them as a group, i.e. each individual checkbox is not required (again giving the default client-side validation nothing to attach to). Otherwise, you would have to check each one to pass validation. So, instead, there has to be code that checks the group as a whole to ensure that at least one is actually checked.

Comment: I don't believe it has any JS with it.  How can I go about creating custom validation for this?  I originally downloaded the package because I wanted a simple way to create checkboxes for a list of objects from my database.  If it's easier to do it another way and get client validation, I'm all for it.